# Android Studio Emulator Problem i cant use emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, android-emulator

Im getting same problem when im trying to run my app on android studio it says error while launching activity here is a photo of error [The Error](http://www.imgim.com/9220incil2518297.png)

Notes:
1)-I already writed -r to install flags
2)-I already disactivated instant run

EDIT:1)http://www.imgim.com/8369incib5094271.png 2)http://www.imgim.com/2752incio6976569.png
3)http://www.imgim.com/5162incis8193748.png

Comment: Does it run with the IDE and without ADB commands? It seems like you already had a successful install so, did you check for the `Activity` to see if it has issue when compiling or not?

Comment: did you try restarting android studio and creating new emulator?

Comment: @Mohsen i cant understand your comment :) what should i do can you tell me more simplified

Comment: @nupadhyaya yes a million times :)

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be with the emulator.. it is not able to launch the activity. Can you post the complete line of `unexpected error while executing`? The last part seems to be clipped out..

Comment: @Mohsen oh yes im using android studio run button

Comment: `nupadhyaya` is right. What I meant is, maybe there are issues with the Activity so that it cannot launch it. We need more details like, any logs (except this screenshot), any other errors or anything helpful.

Comment: @Mohsen i've added 3 new photos also its a deafult empty project i didnt make any change of code or something

Comment: @nupadhyaya i've added 3 new photos of error

Comment: Is you activity mentioned in the manifest

Comment: @Riemann Just checked the images. Does your emulator working properly? It seems like there is no problem with the project. However, images didn't help much I'm afraid. Please check if any crashes or logs saved in the logcat and take an screenshot and let us see what is the issue.